# Error dynamically creating/compiling component and module

Tags: angular, compilation, components

I'm following some examples I've seen and creating and compiling a component at runtime with Angular with the following versions

```
Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.9
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.9
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.9
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.1
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.1
@angular/cdk                      9.2.0
@angular/flex-layout              9.0.0-beta.29
@angular/material                 9.2.0
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.9
@schematics/angular               9.1.1
@schematics/update                0.901.1
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.8.3
webpack                           4.42.0
```

I've got a method that creates the module and component and compiles it. I get a compiled successfully message from the angular cli

```
private createModule(template: string, imports = [], providers = []) {
    @Component({
        selector: 'app-table-cell-content',
        template,
        providers
    })
    class CustomComponent {};

    @NgModule({
        imports: imports ? imports : [],
        declarations: [ CustomComponent ]
    })
    class CustomModule {};

    return this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(CustomModule);
}
```

When the app runs, this actually works and I see my custom content in the component. However, when the code is actually run, in my VSCode console (not in chrome console) I see the following error. This error prevents things like CI from working even though the app runs/works fine, but the compiler doesn't actually catch it until it compiles at runtime

```
    ERROR in src/app/shared/table/table.component.ts:128:14 - error NG1010: template must be a string
    
    128                 template
                        ~~~~~~~~
    src/app/shared/table/table.component.ts:134:13 - error NG1010: Expected array when reading the NgModule.imports of CustomModule
    
    134                 imports
                        ~~~~~~~
```

***EDIT***
I've updated angular to the following but get the same results:

```
Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.12
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.12
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.12
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.12
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.12
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.12
@angular/cdk                      9.2.0
@angular/flex-layout              9.0.0-beta.29
@angular/material                 9.2.0
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.12
@schematics/angular               9.1.12
@schematics/update                0.901.12
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.8.3
webpack                           4.42.0
```

Comment: shouldn't you set template to empty string by default?

Comment: The component needs to be reusable. Is there a way to compile a template and add the template afterward to the component?

Comment: That part of the code was taken from multiple sources as examples that allowed passing in dynamic text for the template